# Avg of avgs in variable time windows

Tags: algorithm

### Context:

- **Activity** has a grade
- Activities belong to a subject, and the **subject_avg** is simply the average of its activities grades in a determined time range
- The **global_avg** is the avg of many **subject_avg** (i.e, not to be confused with the average of all activity grades)

### Problem:

- "Efficiently" calculate **global_avg** in variable time windows

---

"Efficiently" calculating **subject_avg** for a single subject, by accumulating the amount and grade of its activities:

|  | date | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| act1 | day 1 | 0.5 |
| act2 | day 3 | 1 |
| act3 | day 3 | 0.8 |
| act4 | day 6 | 0.6 |
| act5 | day 6 | 0 |

|  | avg_sum | activity_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| day 1 | 0.5 | 1 |
| day 3 | 2.3 | 3 |
| day 6 | 2.6 | 5 |

I called it "efficiently" because if I need **subject_avg** between any 2 dates, I can obtain it with simple arithmetic over the second table:

```
subject_avg (day 2 to 5) = (2.3 - 0.5) / (3 - 1) = 0.6
```

---

Calculating **global_avg**:

**subjectA**

|  | avg_sum | activity_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| day 1 | 0.5 | 1 |
| day 3 | 2.3 | 3 |
| day 6 | 2.6 | 5 |

**subjectB**

|  | avg_sum | activity_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| day 4 | 0.8 | 1 |
| day 6 | 1.8 | 2 |

```
global_avg (day 2 to 5) = (subjectA_avg + subjectB_avg)/2 =  (0.6 + 0.8) / 2 =  0.7
```

---

I have hundred of subjects, so I need to now: Is there any way I could pre-process the **subject_avgs** so that I don't need to individually calculate its averages in the given time window before calculating **global_avg**?

Comment: Spreadsheet showing what I have tried: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EraUnUQ2rWLKhBnpH7YTdIqgK2cxDtVRHb2Jt4wc_Ak/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How often do you need to calculate that global average? Are you using an SQL database?

Comment: @Olivier It will be available in a user interface (with date pickers), so they can calculate as often as they want. And no, I am using mongoDB (to store activities, answers and answers_grades).

Comment: The pre-processing could be brute forced, but what efficiency/constraints are you looking at?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Not sure I understand you question, but the pre-processing cannot be like "precalculate global_avg one at a time for all possible time intervals" since this would be a huge amount of data to send to client (and probably could take very long, and the processing in syncronous so it can't take more than 30s).

Comment: How are you defining subject_avg for days/intervals with no activities? So for example, what's global_avg for just day 5? What if exactly one subject had activities on that day, do you count the other subject_avg's as 0%, 100%, or ignore them? Are date ranges like 'day 2 to 5' including or excluding days 2 and 5? Also, you have hundreds of subjects; do you also have a large number of unique dates?

Comment: @kcsquared global_avg for day 5 is None. Subjects without act are ignored. Date ranges are closed (include both extremities). The dates can vary a lot, so yes, we can have also a large number of unique dates.

Comment: is global_avg for a user-selected set of activities, or is it always calculated for the same set of activities? Also, note that subiect A has more activities than subject B for the given range. Are you sure that they must be weighed the same in the global_avg?

Comment: @maniek it is for a user-selected set of activities. Also, they are being created all the time, but we might be ok in having some time of delay before cosidering them in the global_avg.

Comment: @carla the dates are user selected. The question doesn’t mention the activities being user-selected as well?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I might have phrased it incorrectly. ^^'  It depends on the *user* you select (you dont get to pick the activities themselves). I might be looking at one student global_avg, then I can change to another one.

Comment: @carla The fact that you need to track all the 'Nones' in your sum makes it seem unlikely that an asymptotically faster answer to queries than your `O(#subjects)` current one is known, without using much more space. However, there may be much more efficient solutions than your current code, depending on the specific details of your data. Are entries very sparse, or is there a lot of repetition in the data? Are all of the entries small positive integers? It's very possible that the general problem you describe can be proved to be hard, while you only need a special case.

Comment: @carla Calculating average of averages `(subjectA_avg + subjectB_avg)/2` is really intended here? Normally if you have two averages like `AV1=sum1/n1` and `AV2=sum2/n2` then the new average would be calculated like `AV3=(sum1+sum2)/(n1+n2)` rather than `AV3=(AV1+AV2)/2`

Comment: @Fractal Unfortunately, yes. I had previously designed assuming `(sum1+sum2)/(n1+n2)`, but when I was told the average was different I realized my solution with the accumulated scoring didnt work anymore for the global_avg. =/

Comment: @kcsquared I'd would say the entries can vary a lot (some schools might have determined dates to send activities; others don't, making possibly sparse entries). `grade` is garanted to be a float number between 0 and 1 (it is the result of division of small integers); if it helped I believed we could assume only 2 decimals places, to make its possibilities finite. Unfortunately, given the wide range of possible user scenarios, I couldn't find yet a simplified version of the problem. =/